# Make functions instantiate its generic parameter

Tags: c++, templates, generics, rust

What would be an equivalent to the following C++ program in rust?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
T stuff() {
    return T();
}
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = stuff<std::vector<int>>();
    vec.push_back(1);
    for (auto &&i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```rs
trait Newable{
    fn new() -> Self;
}
fn stuff<T: Newable>() -> T {
    T::new()
}
```

I tried using a newtype for this -

```rs
struct NwVec<T>{
    vec: Vec<T>
}
impl<T> Newable<T> for NwVec<T>{
    fn new() -> Self {
        NwVec { vec: Vec::new() }
    }
}
```

and used it like so:

```rs
fn main() {
    let x: NwVec<i32> = stuff::<NwVec<i32>>();
}
```

but I get a

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `NwVec<i32>: Newable<NwVec<i32>>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:2:25
   |
2  |     let x: NwVec<i32> = stuff();
   |                         ^^^^^ the trait `Newable<NwVec<i32>>` is not implemented for `NwVec<i32>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <NwVec<T> as Newable<T>>
note: required by a bound in `stuff`
```

Is there a way to achieve what the C++ program achieves?

P.S.: I am rather new to rust, I am really sorry if the solution to this is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there was a mixup when you entered the code that you say gave you the error you provided, because that same code did not yield that specific error when I tried it.

Either way, you were close. Consider this code:

```
trait Newable {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

fn stuff<T: Newable>() -> T {
    T::new()
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NwVec<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> Newable for NwVec<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        NwVec { vec: Vec::new() }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: NwVec<i32> = stuff::<NwVec<i32>>();
    
    println!("{x:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=039b42c19478deaa1ae49584db892a51)

All I changed was:

- Added `#[derive(Debug)]` to `NwVec<T>` so we could print it out
- I removed the type parameter `<T>` on `Newable<T>` from your original `impl<T> Newable<T> for NwVec<T>`. This is because the `Newable` trait itself, as provided in your post, is not generic, so it takes no type parameter.

I imagine this is something of a learning exercise, but in case you were curious, you may be interested in [`std::default::Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) which is a trait somewhat similar to your `Newable` in that implementations provide a simple and consistent way to create a "default" version of something. `Vec` itself is an implementer, so you can call e.g. `Default::default()` or `Vec::default()` wherever a `Vec<T>` is expected. Check [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9a7c82e2401945d6f00383dc17e9cba).

Comment: yea this is meant to be just something i was curious about as i heard rust does not have type erasure, anyways thanks.

Comment: @yaxleypeaks Rust does have type erasure in the form of `dyn Trait`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman my bad, i should have been more specific. rust does not have type erasure when not using trait objects.

Comment: @yaxleypeaks But how is that related here? Also, this is like saying C++ doesn't have type erasure when not using inheritance. True, but meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the excellent answer by @JorgeIsraelPeña, in case you insist on `Newable`, you don't need a newtype. You can implement a trait for a type as long as *either* the trait *or* the type are yours (well, the actual rules are [a bit more complicated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence)). That means you can implement `Newable` directly for `Vec`:

```rust
impl<T> Newable for Vec<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Vec::new()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = stuff::<Vec<i32>>();

    println!("{x:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=110388acb51b8020abd371e236e6ea57).

Comment: No, i do not insist on Newable at all. what would be the shortest implementation of this

Comment: @yaxleypeaks Using `Default`.